# How to know if this request triggered by a redirection in Silex?

Tags: php, redirect, silex

I have a PHP web app with Silex. In a certain url I need to know if the page is redirected, and if so, is redirected from which url. I tried `$request->headers->get('referer'))` but  It always has a value, even when the request is triggered by a click on another page. I tried to use a "url interface" fro redirection like this:

```
$app->get('/redirect/{url}', function (\Silex\Application $app, $url) {
    $url=str_replace("!","/",$url);
    return $app->redirect($url,302);
});
```

and for instance changed my redirect to `/sell/insert` into a redirection to `/redirect/!sell!insert`. But this time `$request->headers->get('referer'))` returns the first url, not `/redirct`.

So how can I know if the request is triggered by a redirection, and if so, is redirected from which url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having your example in mind, you can send the url as a GET parameter, and check the request for it, instead of checking the referer. Another way would be to store the url in the session before doing the redirect, and then check the session in the route/s you are expecting it.

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you may be also interesed in [forwarding](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html#forwards) instead of redirecting.